# ? Operator VS ?? Operator Usage

Tags: c#

The following statement works:

```
Class.ID = odrDataReader["ID"] == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(odrDataReader["ID"]);
```

But the following does not:

```
Class.ID = odrDataReader["ID"] as int? ?? 0; //ID is always 0
```

Any one can explain why ?? operator always returns 0 even when ID column is not null?

Solution(suggested by Kirk):

```
Class.ID = Convert.ToInt32(odrDataReader["ID"] ?? 0);
```

Comment: I'd check to verify that odrDataReader["ID"] is returning something that can be forced into an int.  If it's some object type, it can't be AS'ed into an int and what's going into the ?? is always null, therefore the result will always be 0.

Comment: It's actually the [`?:` (ternary) operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) even though it has the form `cond ? iftrue : otherwise`.

Comment: @pst: Minor nitpick, it is called the _conditional_ operator.  It just happens to be _the_ only ternary operator in the language.

Comment: It's actually the [`?:` (conditional) operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) even though it has the form `cond ? iftrue : otherwise` :-)

Comment: Note that this is a situation where you *cannot* use the `??` (null coalescing) operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In first one you use `Convert.ToInt32(odrDataReader["ID"])` in second one you use `odrDataReader["ID"] as int?`.
From what you say first one is correct, so you should use Convert in second too.

Actualy I think first is fine, because it would look weird if you really wanted to use ?? operator.

**Edit**:
To explain a bit `odrDataReader["ID"] as int?` is NOT a conversion. It will always return null if odrDataReader["ID"] is string.

Comment: That would just defeat the purpose of ?? operator.

Comment: But odrDataReader["ID"] always contains some number.

Comment: But as what type? Run a debuger and look as what type it is. My guess its a string.

Comment: Yea its a string. I did this in the debugger "267" as int?. The error description explained it well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the type of the `ID` column.  If it was indeed of type `int?`, then you should be able to do this with no problems:

```
Class.ID = (int?)odrDataReader["ID"] ?? 0;
```

However it is more likely that this is not the case and is a different type (I'd guess `string`).  A `string` is clearly not a `int?` and thus `odrDataReader["ID"] as int?` always returns `null` and you get the value `0`.  As Euphoric mentions, the `as` operator only does reference/boxing conversions.  If this is the case, using `??` is not an option for you and you must use the first expression.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely because you are doing `odrDataReader["ID"] as int?` - that is the difference between the two statements, and using the `as` keyword is not the same as doing a `Convert`.

If you want to use `??` you could try

```
Class.ID = Convert.ToInt32(odrDataReader["ID"] ?? 0);
```

Comment: Nice.. slick solution.. thanx.

Comment: Both operands to the `??` operator must be compatible types.  That would work iff the static type of `odrDataReader["ID"]` was `int?`.  Any other types (`object` included) would produce a compiler error.  An explicit cast would be needed (but would fail).

Answer (score 0):

Misread the question. I'm guessing it's because you're casting odrDataReader["ID"] to int? before checking it. You should try skipping the cast, though I doubt that's what's really the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Coalescing operator is new operator added in C#2.0. Coalescing operator is also known as ??.

```
Nullable<int> a = null;
Nullable<int> b = 10;
int c = a ?? b.Value;
```

Coalescing operator
Coalescing operator work some what similar to ternary operator but it works only with the Nullable types only. so its sort hand operator to deal with Nullable types only.

check my blog post : [Coalescing operator - ??](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/12/coalescing-operator.html)

Comment: Does this answer the question in any way?

Comment: @kirk - read the question title (? Operator VS ?? Operator Usage) as per this title i say its right

Comment: You answered the title, not the question.

Comment: The question is not "Please tell me about ?? operator" - it is actually "Any one can explain why ?? operator always returns 0 even when ID column is not null?".

Answer (score 0):

the ?? operator is the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx). It defines a default value if the value is found to be null. Int32 is a value type in .NET, which normally can't take a null value, so the `int?` designates an Int32 that can be null.

Comment: Does this answer the question in any way?

Comment: hmm... sort of but not fully. I thought that given some clarification on why it was not operating the way he expected (i.e. telling him how the operators work) would clear up the confusion. I think that **learning why** is more important than spoon-feeding the answer.